# FK causing a crash while creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

The following `CREATE TABLE` doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transacciones`.`jos_trans_sector` (
  `id_sector` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_sector`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sector_empresa_sector1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_sector`)
    REFERENCES `transacciones`.`jos_trans_empresa_sector` (`id_sector`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I get:
`Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'transacciones.jos_trans_sector' (errno: 150)`

If I use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` i get the following output:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
170509 16:14:06 Error in foreign key constraint of table transacciones/jos_trans_sector:

    FOREIGN KEY (`id_sector`)
    REFERENCES `transacciones`.`jos_trans_empresa_sector` (`id_sector`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the [...]
```

I've checked some post where they talk about different types between the `id` and the `FK`, but I've the same for both (`INT`)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a primary key on jos_trans_empresa_sector for the FK to reference?

Comment: There is no "crash" and the error is pretty obvious.  Declare the appropriate column in the referencing table as `unique` or as a `primary key`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew I had to create `indexes` when I was creating `N-M` relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the `transacciones.jos_trans_empresa_sector` table is missing an index on the `id_sector` column, so the foreign key cannot be created.

Try adding a unique index:

```
ALTER TABLE transacciones.jos_trans_empresa_sector
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_id_sector (id_sector);
```

and then trying to create the table again.

Comment: You need a Primary Key or Unique Index on that column. Otherwise you cant reference that column as FK

Comment: Yes, adding index on the column and then setting up the foreign key works